# How to compute values of function, f(X,Y), over a range of values of X and Y in two separate lists

Tags: python, function

I have two lists with variables x and y. They are sorted out in a sense that x[n] corresponds to y[n], where n is the index of the list. I need to compute f(x,y). The function is a simple polynomial depending on x and y. Say, f(x,y) = x^2+2xy.Below, I will put the code I tried which did not work.

```
list_x=[1,2,3,4,5]
list_y=[2,4,5,8,10]
x=list_x[n]
y=list_y[n]
def f(x,y):
    for n in range (0,4):
         return x**2+2*x*y 

print(f(x,y))
```

Comment: What is `f(x,y)` supposed to do?

Comment: Provide more detail in the function and related functions if possible, hard to know what your intention is

Comment: @Cacoon it's a simple polynomial function

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a list of result, then using numpy

```
import numpy as np
list_x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
list_y=np.array([2,4,5,8,10])
def f(x,y):
    return x**2+2*x*y 

print(f(list_x,list_y))


output
[  5  20  39  80 125]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays were made for this. We just need to convert your lists to numpy arrays and we are basically done.

`x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

`y = np.array([2,4,5,8,10])`

Then this just works.

`x**2+2*x*y`

Answer (score 0):

Without any external library:

```
list_x=[1,2,3,4,5]
list_y=[2,4,5,8,10]
results = map(lambda x,y: x**2 + 2*x*y, zip(list_x, list_y)
```

`retults` will be generator with all computed values, which you then can convert to `list` with `list(result)` or just use in for-loop.